# Robot Framework tests using Sikulilibrary working in Selenium Grid?

Tags: robotframework, selenium-grid, sikuli

Anyone got mentioned combination to work? I've set up grid following this https://github.com/sterodium/selenium-grid-extensions and grid setup itself seems to be ok but when I'm actually running tests where sikulilibrary keywords are used I'm getting following error; *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.sikuli.script.Finder$Finder2*.

My grid setup:

- robotframework 3.1.2
- robotframework-seleniumlibrary 3.3.1
- robotframework-SikuliLibrary 1.0.8
- selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
- extension-proxy-1.0.jar
- all-node-extensions-1.0.jar

Hub start:
java -cp selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar;extension-proxy-1.0.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 -role hub -hubConfig hub.json

hub.json:

```
{
  "port": 4444,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlet": "io.sterodium.extensions.hub.proxy.HubRequestsProxyingServlet",
  "capabilityMatcher": "io.sterodium.extensions.capability.CustomCapabilityMatcher",
  "prioritizer": null,
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 1800,
  "browserTimeout": 70000,
  "maxSession": 5,
  "debug": false,
  "jettyMaxThreads": -1
}
```

Node start:
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe -cp selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar;all-node-extensions-1.0.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 -role node -nodeConfig node.json

node.json:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "extension.sikuliCapability": true
    }

  ],
  "host": "X.X.X.X",
  "port": 5561,
  "maxSession": 10,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://X.X.X.X:4444/hub/wd/",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "servlets" : ["io.sterodium.extensions.node.SikuliExtensionServlet","io.sterodium.extensions.node.upload.FileUploadServlet","io.sterodium.extensions.node.download.FileDownloadServlet"],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some version mixup:

`org.sikuli.script.Finder$Finder2` is of SikuliX version 1.1.4,

but you have the `robotframework-SikuliLibrary 1.0.8` (current version which uses SikuliX 1.1.4 is 1.4)

see: https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary

(RaiMan from SikuliX)

Comment: I'm doing a fresh installation using 'pip install robotframework-SikuliLibrary' so, I suppose it's 1.1.4 although it diplays as 1.0.8? At least this seems to be the case in all systems where I've installed SikuliLibrary.